# Indexing matrices with four indices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

The usual way to index elements in a matrix (in MATLAB, at least) is to use two variables (*i* and *j*), so a general element matrix can be adressed by M_{i,j}. How can I do the same indexing in a matrix that has four indices, like M_{ij,kl}?

**EDIT**

The elements of a usual matrix A can be viewed as:

[image: matrix]

So a general element is extracted, in MATLAB, using A(n,m). 
What I want to do is write a matrix that has elements that are indexed like this:

[matrix2 http://bit.ly/1gHRZrR](http://bit.ly/1gHRZrR)

Is there any way to do this without using cells/arrays, as pointed out in the comments of the question?

Comment: What do you mean with 'four indices'? You want a range of indices from a 2d matrix? or you want one element from a four-dimensional matrix? and btw the `{}` are used for cell arrays

Comment: matrices by definition only have two dimensions otherwise operations on them would not be so well defined. But you could be using cells instead. try m = cell(1,2,3,4) which gives you a quasi matrix in four dimensions with sizes 1,2,3,4 (indexable as you want with m{1,1,3,1} or likewise)

Comment: Two indices: `M(i,j)`. Four indices: `M(i,j,k,l)`. So what's the question?

Comment: I think my question was not clear. I want to index elements in a matrix using to indices for lines and two indices for rows!

Comment: @Filou As you said, operations get difficult when dealing with this kind of matrices. What I wanted to do is take some elements from this matrix and multiply them by some other matrices.

Comment: @RodrigoThomas Your question is very vague. I suggest you draw us a mock matrix and highlight exactly which elements you are trying to index. But also read through this: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: I think he means this: `M([i,j], [k,l])` will yield a two by two matrix with `M(i,k)`, `M(i,k)`, `M(j,k)`, and `M(kj,l)`.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I assume you would like to extract elements with multiple (two) row and column indices. Given a matrix `M = magic(5);`, e.g.

```
17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

you can indeed index `M` with multiple row and  column indices as in `M([3,4], [1,5])` which would yield a two by two matrix:

```
 4    22
10     3
```